# Run function only once

Tags: jquery, animation, slider

I'm looking to have this only happen once and not every time the third slide is equal to the current slide. How would i do that? would .once() work for this?

```
var currentSlide = current - 1;
var firstSlide = $('#slide1').index();
var secondSlide = $('#slide2').index();
var thirdSlide = $('#slide3').index();
if (thirdSlide == currentSlide) {
    $('img.joyceAnim').flipbook({
        'end': 4,
        'loop': false,
        'fps': 8,
        'mobileStep': 1,
        'images': 'anim/bench/%d.png'
    });
}​
```

Comment: Easiest way make a `flag=0` and when function runs check `if (!flag)`, then when function finishes set `flag=1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentSlide = current-1; 
var firstSlide = $('#slide1').index();
var secondSlide = $('#slide2').index();
var thirdSlide = $('#slide3').index();
var doIt = true;

if((thirdSlide == currentSlide) && doIt){
    doIt = false;
    $('img.joyceAnim').flipbook({
        'end': 4,
        'loop': false,
        'fps': 8,
        'mobileStep': 1,
        'images': 'anim/bench/%d.png'
    });   

}
```

Just make a switch to see if you should do it.

Comment: try now; I added some parenthesis

Comment: @Brent you're welcome :) and also, alot [(link)](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html) :P

Comment: For this to work, `doIt` has to be a global variable.  So, this exact code can't be inside a function (without modifying the way `doIt` is declared).

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `.data()` indicator on the element when you've already animated it once and then check that indicator before animating it again:

```
var currentSlide = current-1; 
var firstSlide = $('#slide1').index();
var secondSlide = $('#slide2').index();
var thirdSlide = $('#slide3').index();
var flip = $('img.joyceAnim');
var alreadyFlipped = flip.data("flipped");

if(thirdSlide == currentSlide && !alreadyFlipped){
    flip.data("flipped", true).flipbook({
        'end': 4,
        'loop': false,
        'fps': 8,
        'mobileStep': 1,
        'images': 'anim/bench/%d.png'
    });   

}
```